# Add Doublequotes for all columns in text file with bash

Tags: linux, bash, text

Sorry for bad format... now it shows the point:

(columns - tab delimited) 
Input:

1     2     3     4

5     6     7     8

some columns may looks like this:

1 some text     2 text with space     3 lots of `:"'etc.     4

5     6     7     8

How to make output:

"1"     "2"     "3"     "4"

"5"     "6"     "7"     "8"

Or even better:

"1","2","3","4"

"5","6","7","8"

Got it! It's a bit stupid... but works:

sed 's/\t/","/g' input.txt | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'

first sed is changing tabs to "," and next one is adding " at the beginning and the end of line.

Comment: Not good... format is broken during writing this topic -sorry. It should be:
Input:
row1_column1 tab row1_column2 tab row1_cloumn3 tab row1_column4

row2_column1 tab row2_column2 tab row2_cloumn3 tab row2_column4

Answer (score 1):

Replace each tab with `", "`, put an extra `"` to the beginning an to the end:

```
string=$'1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8'
echo \"${string//$'\t'/\", \"}\"
```

Comment: Although it looks ugly, the expansion should have another set of unescaped double quotes surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I know of uses `perl`:

```
while read; do
  IFS=$'\t' perl -e '$,=","; $\="\n"; print map(qq/"$_"/, @ARGV); ' $REPLY
done < input.txt
```

A pure `bash` solution that requires a temporary variable:

```
while read; do
  IFS=$'\t' printf -v var '"%s",' $REPLY
  echo "${var%,}"
done < input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is also making trouble when string has space in it, for example row1, column1:
no_space_text --> "no_space_text" but:
 text with space --> "text","with","space" and I need "text with space"

Comment: In the updated answer, I set `IFS` to split words only on tabs, so that "test with space\tanother test" will split into 2 "words", not 5.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo -e '1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8' | sed 's/[^\t]\+/"&"/g;y/\t/,/'
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"
```

Comment: sed 's/\S\+/"&"/g;s/\s\+/,/g' input_file
this works great! Thank you very much.

Comment: unfortunately not exactly... some entries in one column are like            
10 name                  and this sed is making from it "10" "name" instead of "10 name" ...

Comment: @user1443373 amended solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in `perl` should work:

```perl
perl -F'\t' -lape '$_ = qw(") . join(qw(","), @F) . qw(")' infile
```

It splits each line of `infile` at tab chars and joins them with `","` while also pre- and appending `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash, for tab delimited output:

```
while read  line ; do
  echo -e "\"${line//$'\t'/\"\t\"}\""
done < "$infile"
```

for comma delimited output:

```
while read  line ; do
  echo -e "\"${line//$'\t'/\",\"}\""
done < "$infile"
```

Spaces inside strings are allowed.